# Xcode 9 can't merge branch of SpriteKit app

Tags: xcode, merge, version-control, sprite-kit, crash

With Xcode 9 and specifically a SpriteKit app, I can't merge a branch of source code into master.  It causes Xcode to crash.  (The merge works OK with a single-pane application.)

Steps:
1. Create new SpriteKit app.
2. Create a branch off 'master' named 'Test'
3. Create some trivial change in the Test branch.
4. Commit the changes.
5. Right click 'master' and choose "Merge Test into master."
6. Xcode crashes

Can others reproduce this?  For me, it happens every time.